# Timestamp problem for specific sheet and multiple columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have sheet which generates timestamp when Column 2 is edited to Column 1 and if Col 14 is edited to col 15. That needs to be in specific sheet. My code is now:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Outbound" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "") {
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

How I can get that work, with multiple columns with different columns which are edited and for specific sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recommendation:

The script below will show the timestamp in column 1 when column 2 is edited same goes when there's changes in column 14, it will show the timestamp in column 15.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var date = new Date();
  
  if(sheetName == 'Outbound' && column == 2)
  {  
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Outbound').getRange(row,1).setValue(date);    
  } 
  if (sheetName == 'Outbound' && column == 14)
  {  
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Outbound').getRange(row,15).setValue(date);    
  } 
}
```

### Sample Output:

Column 2:

[image: column2]

Column 14:

[image: column14]

### References:

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [new Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Comment: Thank you! It is working. But if I add similar script with another sheet tab to create different timestamps there, it stops working. What should I do?

Comment: Never mind! I missed a few things. Thank you

Comment: It's good to know it is working now. If this answers your question, you can click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const n = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  if (n == "Outbound") {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 2) {
      e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date());
    } else if (e.range.columnStart == 14) {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```